# Enable|Disable radio(child) with checkbox (parent)

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I've a list of checkboxes and radiogroups like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv1 value=1>ВъездАвто</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=6000><a>г/п 10Т</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;6000</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;1200</a></td>
</tr> 
<tr>

<td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=4200><a>г/п 7Т</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;4200</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;840</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=3000><a>г/п 5Т</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;3000</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;600</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=1800><a>г/п 3Т</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;1800</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;360</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv2 value=2>ХранСутки40фут</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td><input type=radio id=servch2 name=servch2 value=5300><a>гружен.</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;5300</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;1060</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch2 name=servch2 value=3000><a>порожн.</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;3000</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;600</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv3 value=3>ХранСутки20фут</td>
</tr> 
<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch3 name=servch3 value=2600><a>гружен.</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;2600</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;520</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch3 name=servch3 value=1600><a>порожн.</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;1600</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;320</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv4 value=4>Очистка конт.</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td><input type=radio id=servch4 name=servch4 value=2700><a>среднетон.</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;2700</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;540</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch4 name=servch4 value=6300><a>20фут</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;6300</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;1260</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr><td><input type=radio id=servch4 name=servch4 value=11500><a>40фут</a></td>
<td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;11500</a></td>
<td><a>НДС:&nbsp;2300</a></td></tr> <tr><td></table>
```

I want enable|disable child radio group with his parent checkbox. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing your HTML wouldn't hurt...

Let's say it looks like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="c1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="c1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" value="1" />
</div>
```

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
      $(this).nextAll("input:radio").attr("disabled",true);
    }
    else{
      $(this).nextAll("input:radio").attr("disabled",null);
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

I'd suggest first you divide your table into TBODYs:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv1 value=1>ВъездАвто</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=6000><a>г/п 10Т</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;6000</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;1200</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=4200><a>г/п 7Т</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;4200</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;840</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=3000><a>г/п 5Т</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;3000</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;600</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch1 name=servch1 value=1800><a>г/п 3Т</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;1800</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;360</a></td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3><input type=checkbox class="filter-checkbox" name=serv2 value=2>ХранСутки40фут</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch2 name=servch2 value=5300><a>гружен.</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;5300</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;1060</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type=radio id=servch2 name=servch2 value=3000><a>порожн.</a></td>
                <td><a>Сумма:&nbsp;3000</a></td>
                <td><a>НДС:&nbsp;600</a></td>
            </tr>
            ....
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(function(){
  $("table input:checkbox").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
      $(this).parents("tbody").find("input:radio").attr("disabled",true);
    }
    else{
      $(this).parents("tbody").find("input:radio").attr("disabled",null);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: thank you Nabab, but my checkboxes and radios placed in a table:

Comment: @Andreas: What's wrong? You're talking about the jQuery attr which should be attr("disabled","disabled") ??

Comment: @Nabab: the value you are asigning to the attribute `checked` is not xhtml-valid! `checked` as value or not attribute `checked`

Comment: What are you talking about? I am not assigning any value to checked, I just verify through jQuery selector ":checked" what is the checkbox state (checked or not). Or I didn't understand?

Comment: Thank you Nabab, your script works fine!
But may be I coudnt explain you, 
I want that if parent checkbox checked, child radio group would be active, if parent checkbox not checked, child radio group would be disabled

Comment: They are not child, they are all in sibling rows! Using the method I wrote up there, with the TBODY would work

Comment: I see bro Nabab, I want reverse that you did. Something like this:
if(checkbox.checked)
 {radio.disabled=false;}
 else
 {radio.disabled=true;}

Comment: @Andreas Niedermai : 1- You don't know if the OP wants XHTML! (AFAIK, it could even be `<!DOCTYPE html>` in this case. 2- Please don't refer to [w3schools](http://w3fools.com), it's full of crap. For real reference to the specification, look for **w3c**. 3- I don't see any problem here with the answer and `checked`. 4- Still, you're kinda right! @Nabab forget to close some attributes (ie `<input type=radio ` which won't validate.

Comment: @Shikiryu: In my code they're properly closed. I didn't bother correcting his that I copy/pasted (after EDIT)

Comment: @Nabab : it's still **your** answer (even with copy/paste). If you don't correct him, at least, mention it.

Comment: @Shikiryu: No. I don't think it has to be mentioned - as his code is not XHTML.

Comment: Well, do as you want, it's your answer anyway. It'd just add some quality required for an upvote to me.

Comment: @Shikiryu: 1. it's not about what the OP wants, it's just not a good idea to "code" html for legacy reasons :) 2. i know that w3schools isn't that good place for real references - but the content about xhtml-attributes is 100% valid. so there ain't no reason to not support this w3schools-link. 3. me neither 4. i know :)

Comment: @Andreas : 1- as you say, he _code_ **html**. Both syntax are _valid_ (even if I prefer the XHTML one too) 2- If you know, don't use it ;) Use [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative) instead.

Comment: @Shikiryu: 1. nope, i said `it's just not a good idea to "code" html for legacy reasons`. :) 2. thanks for the link!